# How do I precede a chapter number with 0?

Tags: numbering, chapters

I'm using the `memoir` class to typeset a novel. I have formatted the chapter display as below. The chapter numbers are displayed as '1', '2', '3', etc. How do I pad the chapter numbers less than 10, using a '0'?

```
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\huge}
{\HUGE\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{42pt}]
```

Comment: `0\thechapter` -- that's all. If you want to achieve this scheme everywhere, better use `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{0\arabic{chapter}}`

Comment: Extra question: what should happen at chapter 10?

Comment: @daleif: Well, there's no indication that `0` means padding. Perhaps it's `010`, `011` then...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you for pointing out the ambiguity in the question. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
```